# Shopify - Debut Theme - Showing A Textbox if Certain Variant is Selected

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I'm trying to show my "Embossing" textbox only when the "Style" dropdown option "Embossing" is selected. I've added the below code in my new template, product-customizable-template.liquid, which created the textbox but I want to hide it unless "Embossing" is selected.

```
<p class="line-item-property__field">
<label for="embossing">Embossing</label>
<input required class="required" id="embossing" type="text" name="properties[Embossing]">
</p>
```

["Style" Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt9al.png)

The Style textbox has the following code:

```
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-customizable-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
<option value="None" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="Embossing">Embossing</option>
<option value="Stamp">Stamp</option>
</select>
```

I am still working on the site, so it is not active right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on-page `load` and on `change` of `select` box using Javascript and you can add and remove custom code to form easily

You can check and try the below snippet for a better idea

```
// on change test for your condition
document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
   _checkAndAppend();
});

// run on page load and check the for value and add if selected value meet condition
_checkAndAppend();

function _checkAndAppend() {
   var item = document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0');
   var itemValue = document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').value;
   if (itemValue == 'Embossing') { 
      var input = `<p class="line-item-property__field _embossing">
            <label for="embossing">Embossing</label>
            <input required class="required" id="embossing" type="text" name="properties[Embossing]">
            </p> `;
      item.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',input);
   } else {
      if(document.querySelector('._embossing')){
         document.querySelector('._embossing').remove();
      }      
   }
}
```